# Post method not working in laravel 5.4 from web route

Tags: php, laravel-5

POST method not working in laravel 5.4 , GET method is working same controller.

```
 Route::get('/route','PostController@custon_function'); //working

 Route::post('/route','PostController@custon_function'); //throw error
```

[image]

Comment: Btw it spells `custom`

Comment: Yeah it spells custom,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can combine `GET` and `POST` method with one route this way:

```
Route::match(array('GET','POST'),'/route','PostController@custom_function');
```

**Option 2**

Or you can use this alternative:

```
Route::any('/route', 'PostController@custom_function');
```

And within controller/function, you can check method name this way:

```
if (Request::isMethod('post'))
{
// ... this is POST method
}
if (Request::isMethod('get'))
{
// ... this is GET method
}
```